# Argparse and several exclusive arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to implement the Caesar cipher in `python`, and I'm using `argparse` to parse the arguments.

However I don't know how to create several exclusive arguments like this:

```
caesar.py        ,-   '-b'
                /
    '-d' --- xor
   /            \
 xor             `-   '-k key'
   \
    '-e' ---  '-k key'
```

1. You must specify either `-d` or `-e` (exclusive).
2. If you specify `-e` you must specify `-k`. `-b` is forbidden.
3. If you specify `-d` you must specify either `-k` or `-b` (exclusive).

Here is what I made:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Caesar Cipher")

parser.add_argument("text", nargs="?", help="message to encode/decode")

parser_code = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
parser_code.add_argument("-e", action="store_true", help="encode")
parser_code.add_argument("-d", action="store_true", help="decode")

parser_decode = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
parser_decode.add_argument('-k', type=int, dest="key",   help="key to use")
parser_decode.add_argument('-b', action="store_true" help="bruteforce the key")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Actually, it doesn't work. Indeed, I can still use:

```
python caesar.py -e -b message
```

The option `-b` should be meaningless. I know I could simply do a check and call `parser.print_help()`, however I want this check to be made during the parsing, such as the exclusive one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `argparse` has any provision to allow your situation. The best I can think of is to use sub parsers:

### caesar.py:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    actions = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action')

    encode_parser = actions.add_parser('encode')
    encode_parser.add_argument('-k', type=int, dest="key", help="key to use")

    decode_parser = actions.add_parser('decode')
    decode_parser.add_argument('-k', type=int, dest="key", help="key to use")
    decode_parser.add_argument('-b', dest='bruce_force', action='store_true')

    print parser.parse_args()
```

### Sample Usages:

```
./caesar.py encode -k 5
./caesar.py decode -k 9 -b
```

Comment: Given that `-k` is both the only legal "option" with `encode` and is required, I would drop it and make it another positional parameter: `caesar encode 5`. For `decode`, `-k` and `-b` should be members of a mutually exclusive group as in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Is it good programming design to make `argparse` do something that it wasn't designed to do?

You have defined two mutually exclusive groups of arguments, in effect an `xor` test on their occurance.  But `argparse` does not implement nesting.  I think you could put these two groups in another mutually exclusive group, but the net effect is to put all arguments in one big group - i.e. allow only one of the whole set.

I have explored in a bug/issue the idea of implementing nesting, and groups that could implement any sort of logical relation (xor, or (= any), and (=all).  But it's a complex addition.  One of the messier aspects was formatting the nested relations in the usage display.  Simple mutually exclusive groups are messy enough.

How would you explain, to your users, which combinations of arguments are allowed?

I think your best choice is to judiciously define defaults, so you can clearly tell which arguments have been given, and which haven't, and then perform your tests after parsing.

For 'store_true' arguments you can just test the truth value of the namespace attribute.  For ones that store a value, testing `is None` is usually a good indicator. You user can't provide a `None` value, so `args.dest is None` clearly means that the argument was not used.

With that it's just a matter of writing the nested `if` tests:

```
if args.one and args.two is None:
    if args.three is not None:
        parser.error('three cannot occur with one and two')
etc.
```

`argparse` is best seen as a parser - something that figures out what the user wants.  You can use `argparse` to perform some simple tests, and inform the user when some combination of arguments is incompatible.  But it shouldn't be the primary tool for testing and using arguments.  Your own code should have ultimate responsibility for that.